# How to show $ IFFT\:(\:FFT\:(\:x\:)\:) = x $?

Tags: computer-science, signal-processing, fast-fourier-transform

Can you show the steps to get $f[m,n] = f[m,n]$ for this?

$$ f[m',n'] = IFFT \: ( FFT \: ( \: f[m',n'] \: ) \: ) $$

$$ f[m',n'] = \sum_{k=0}^{M-1}\sum_{l=0}^{N-1}
\left[\frac{1}{MN}\sum_{m=0}^{M-1}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}(f[m,n]e^{-j2\pi(\frac{km}{M}+\frac{ln}{N})}) \right]e^{j2\pi(\frac{km'}{M}+\frac{ln'}{N})}$$

It is a discrete time fourier transform. The reason I'm asking this is I will add an additional $e^{something}$ term after the FFT and take it out of the summation term.

Comment: You have $m$ and $n$ as summation variables on the right hand side and as variables on the left hand side. This is bound to lead to mistakes. You should write it as $f[m',n'] = [\ldots] e^{j 2\pi (\frac{km'}{M} + \frac{ln'}{N})}$ or similar instead.

Comment: To show this try to evaluate the $k$ and $l$ sums first. For this try you will encounter geometrical series like $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{\ell = 0}^{N-1} e^{2\pi j \ell (n' - n)/N}$. This will have one value if $n=n'$ and another value otherwise which will significantly simplify the remaining two sums.

Comment: Thanks @Winther. Are you referring to kronecker delta? Fixing the equation right now.

Comment: Fixed the formula so that its correct. Yes that is what that expression will turn out to be. Once you have showed this the sum you have reduces to $\sum_{m}\sum_n f(m,n)\delta(n,n')\delta(m,m')$ which is not hard to evaluate as only one single term will be nonzero.